# Connotation of 酩酊 (meitei), meaning "drunkenness"?

Tags: word-choice, words, food, connotation

In Yakuza Judgement, a person (who allegedly committed murder) was described with the phrase "酩酊状態にあった" (they were found in a state of drunkenness). However, the official subs translate/localize this as "[he] was drunk out of his mind".
So I was wondering, what level of inebriation does 酩酊 (meitei) imply? Is it just plain "drunk", or something stronger, like "shit-faced" or "piss-drunk"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means usually *very drunk*, the state of being still conscious and barely able to walk.

There are technical definitions [by Ministry of Health, Labor and Welfare](https://www.e-healthnet.mhlw.go.jp/information/dictionary/alcohol/ya-020.html):

> 酩酊初期（血中アルコール濃度110～150mg/dl）
> 症状：気が大きくなる、立てばふらつく
>
> 酩酊極期（血中アルコール濃度160～300mg/dl）
> 症状：何度も同じことをしゃべる、千鳥足

血中アルコール濃度 should be [BAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_alcohol_content), but not sure if they are exactly the same thing.

---

Not that people use 酩酊 according to the technical definition, but generally it is understood as 'very drunk but not alarmingly so*.